# angular-uploadcare $parse undefined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uploadcare

Implementing angular-uploadcare module which can be found [here](https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare).

Seems to work, but Chrome is giving line 34 $parse undefined error. How can this be addressed?

I've pasted the code below.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name angular-uploadcare.directive:Uploadcare
 * @description Provides a directive for the Uploadcare widget.
 * # Uploadcare
 */
angular.module('ng-uploadcare', [])
  .directive('uploadcareWidget', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      require: 'ngModel',
      template: '<input type="hidden" role="ng-uploadcare-uploader" />',
      scope: {
        onWidgetReady: '&',
        onUploadComplete: '&',
        onChange: '&',
      },
      controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$log', function($scope, $element, $log) {
        if(!uploadcare) {
          $log.error('Uploadcare script has not been loaded!.');
          return;
        }
        $scope.widget = uploadcare.Widget($element);
        $scope.onWidgetReady({widget: $scope.widget});
        $scope.widget.onUploadComplete(function(info) {
          $scope.onUploadComplete({info: info});
        });
        $scope.widget.onChange(function(file) {
          // add data binding for hidden inputs
          $scope.$apply(function () {
            $parse($attrs.ngModel).assign($scope.$parent, $element.val());
          });
          $scope.onChange({file: file});
        })
      }]
    };
  });
```

Comment: seems like something that should be available: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

Comment: I did google $parse and found that link, but I'm not great with understanding angular's official documentation.  Could you provide a hint as to what you mean?

Comment: this seems to be a bug in directive, new version is coming up soon

Comment: https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare/pull/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in version 0.1.2. To fix that change the controller signature to:

`controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$parse', '$log', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $parse, $log) {`

Comment: Thanks!  That's funny, I actually had already changed that line in the controller because I think $attrs was missing or misspelled or something like that, but I didn't think to add $parse.  Thanks - great module!

Comment: please consider using the version from this [PR](https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare/pull/9) as it fixes that and also changes behavior a bit (E -> A)